# For Each...Next Help VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, foreach

So. I'm taking ASCII values (numbers) and turning them into ASCII characters (letters and symbols). I've managed to come up with something but when using For Each...Next, it's separating each individual digit. For instance, if I enter 82 (which corresponds to R), I would get whatever corresponds to 8 and whatever corresponds to 2. Is there anyone to indicate that if there are no spaces in between the digits, then it's one single number? Or just overall a way for it to read the numbers, and not the individual digits.

Here is a bit of the code. Should I not be using the Char data type? As I'm assuming that's what's making it convert 1 digit at a time. Though when I tried any other data types, I get some error regarding it not being a collection type.

```
    Dim rtb As String
    rtb = Rich.Text1
    For Each num As Char In rtb
        'Conversion stuff goes here
    Next num
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets analyse what is happening here:

```
For Each num As Char In rtb
```

Since `rtb` is a `String`, and `String` implements `IEnumerable<Char>`, the above is essentially you saying - for each character in the string - which is not what you want.

You need to first split the string into groups that each represents a number - for example:

```
Dim numbers As String() = rtb.Split(" ")
```

Then, you could iterate over the list and convert each of the strings (these are still strings) to a actual number, which you will need to convert to a character:

```
For Each num As String In numbers
   ' num can be "82", for instance
Next num
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
Dim rtb As String = Nothing
rtb = "82 40 30"

For Each num As var In rtb.Split(" "C)
Next
```

Of course if you would like to split numbers using other char just replace " "C with what you need

Answer (score 0):

You’re not iterating over numbers, you’re iterating over individual characters. You didn’t tell us how the numbers are separated in the input but for the sake of discussion let’s assume that you are using spaces. We can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get individual numbers from the stream:

```
Dim rtb As String = "82 23 47 123"
Dim Ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

For each numToken As String In rtb.Split(" "c)
    Dim num As Byte
    If Not Byte.TryParse(numToken, num)
        ' Signal error
        Exit For
    End If

    Dim buffer As Char() = Ascii.GetChars(New Byte() { num })
    Dim result As Char = buffer(0)
    ' Do something with `result`
Next
```

One important bit: I’ve used the `System.Text.Encoding` class to do the mapping between ASCII codes and characters. This may seem unnecessarily complex but do *want to do this*. Encodings unfortunately *are* complex and it’s counter-productive to pretend otherwise and use homegrown ad-hoc conversions. In particular, using `Chr` is *not* appropriate since that doesn’t actually handle ASCII, it handles Unicode code points (with some restrictions) which are similar, but not the same. Using `Chr` in the above code would be misleading and thus a surefire way to introduce bugs further down the road. It’s important to document your assumptions, and if your assumption is that the input consists of ASCII, then the conversion code should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Use three digits for each character. Most lower-case letters are three digits anyway.